# how to chekc that the gpsd is running?

Tags: gpsd

I should make some tests with a GPS module using **gpsd**. I tried to manipulate the position data to a reference point and it works like I expected. Now, the next step will be to verify the maximum "bootup-time" of the **gpsd**.
For this I wait untill the (linux) system was booted completely (this will be signalized over a LED). After that I wait the accepted 15 seconds to initialize the daemon and everything what it needs. After that I want the check the status of the **gpsd**. (Has it booted completely?)

How can I verify that the gpsd is running? Is there any possibility to request the status of the daemon?
Has anyone an idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to gpsd and retrieve sentences with gpspipe.

to get raw sentences: `gpspipe -r`

to get gpsd output: `gpspipe -w`

Also you can check your process to know gpsd is running or not:

`ps aux | grep gpsd`